# Convert Object parameter from VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have below code in VB.NET, it is working well now. I need to convert it to C#. It cannot be compiled because complier dont know about methods of proxy. Can you please let me know how I can convert paramater (Byref proxy as Object) to C#. Thank you so much.

```
Public Shared Function SetupProxy(ByRef proxy As Object) As Boolean
    Dim token As New UsernameToken(Var.sHTNGUsername, Var.sHTNGPassword, PasswordOption.SendPlainText)
    Dim clientPolicy As New Policy

    clientPolicy.Assertions.Add(New UsernameOverTransportAssertion())

    proxy.SetPolicy(clientPolicy)
    proxy.SetClientCredential(token)

    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: `ByRef` is just `ref` in c#

Comment: The code snippet does not show which type "proxy" has. We need to specify it's exact type in C# to use its methods and cast it to it like "<ProxyType> proxyCasted = proxy as <ProxyType>"

Comment: `ref object proxy` that's it

Comment: Use `dynamic` in C# to get the `OPTION STRICT off` behaviour of VB.NET.

Comment: @PacMani But the code is working well on VB.NET, that means C# does not support for binding object at runtime?

Comment: @TimSchmelter That is awsome. No error anymore. I will finish my work first. After that, if it working, I will confirm to you all. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Tung Nguyen: In C#, you must explicitly specify the type name, whereas in VB.NET it seems you do not have to do this. However, it's not recommmended to do so because of type safety and avoiding errors later. The dynamic thingie is indeed interesting.

Answer (score 0):

To invoke dynamically in C#, you can use reflection:

```
public static bool SetupProxy(ref object proxy)
{
    UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken(Var.sHTNGUsername, Var.sHTNGPassword, PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
    Policy clientPolicy = new ClientPolicy();

    clientPolicy.Assertions.Add(new UsernameOverTransportAssertion());

    proxy.GetType().InvokeMember("SetProxy", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, proxy, new object[] { clientPolicy });
    proxy.GetType().InvokeMember("SetClientCredential", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, proxy, new object[] { token });
    return true;
}
```